# Memoization gone wrong or done wrong?

Tags: python, memoization

I'm learning a bit of Python and want to speed up a function with dictionary memoization. But it's getting slower! Is this because of slow dictionaries in Python or because I should have done something other than using `setdefault` ? If so, what instead, what's the recommended and/or fastest way of memoization in Python?

```
D={}
d1=lambda n: D.setdefault( n, 0 if n==1 else 1+d1(n//2 if n%2==0 else n*3+1) )
d2=lambda n:                  0 if n==1 else 1+d2(n//2 if n%2==0 else n*3+1)
for n in range(1,40001): print("d(",n,") =",d2(n))
#print(D)  #to see that D is actually filled
```

The only difference between d1 and d2 is that d1 uses memoization, they both return the same for the same input. The same thing in Perl results in a huge speedup, runtimes:

```
Memoization Python Perl
----------- ------ -----
Yes         1.14s  0.19s
No          0.81s  1.33s
```

Those four tests as oneliners:

```
time python -c'D={};d=lambda n:D.setdefault(n, 0 if n==1 else 1+d(n//2 if n%2==0 else n*3+1));[print("d(",n,")=",d(n)) for n in range(1,40001)]'|tail
time python -c'     d=lambda n:                0 if n==1 else 1+d(n//2 if n%2==0 else n*3+1);[print("d(",n,")=",d(n)) for n in range(1,40001)]'|tail
time perl -E'sub d{my$n=pop;$d{$n}//=do{$n==1?0:1+d($n%2?$n*3+1:$n/2)}}say"d($_)=".d($_) for 1..40000'|tail
time perl -E'sub d{my$n=pop;            $n==1?0:1+d($n%2?$n*3+1:$n/2)}say"d($_)=".d($_) for 1..40000'|tail
```

(d1 and d2 return the stop distance in [collatz series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) where the next number is n/2 when even and 3*n+1 when odd. Example: d(24) = 10 because we need ten steps to reach 1 from 24: 12, 6, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 which is ten steps)

**EDIT:**

After reading the useful comments and answer, I now see that went wrong and have this new faster (0.13s) function d3 which will be my approach on the real code. Or `@lru_cache` if I can get that to work. Seems like a good idea to limit memory use in some cases.

```
def d3(n):
    D[n] = D[n] if n in D else 0 if n==1 else 1+d3(n//2 if n%2==0 else n*3+1)
    return D[n]
```

Comment: The second parameter to `dict.setdefault()` (just like *every* parameter in Python) is fully evaluated before calling the method.  So you're still doing the full recursion, just ignoring the results from cases where you've memoized the results from a previous call.

Comment: To add to what @jasonharper said, you need to explicitly check whether the result is in the dictionary already, and only add it if it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Evaluation of `setdefault` arguments happen before the call, so memoization doesn't actually save any time for you the way you implement d1.

If you want you can use the functools [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

```py
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def d1(n):
    return 0 if n==1 else 1+d1(n//2 if n%2==0 else n*3+1)
```

Comment: I _vastly_ prefer this approach. Python already has a perfectly good memoizing decorator. Unless you have a specific reason not to use it, you should use it. Also, a quick timing test showed this solution to be about 6 times faster than OP's `d2`. Removing the `print` call and just running the function "bare" to remove string formatting overhead made it about 8 times faster than `d2`, and 12 times faster than `d1`.